# Spark with python script from console not working no errors

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, cmd, spark-submit

Hi I got this weird problem. I am new to spark, just installed spark and java, made the environmental variables and spark seems to work properly. I can enter the spark console form cmd and write print ect. its working.

But when I try to do ***bin\spark-submit C:\Users\User\Desktop\Big_Data\pi.py*** where pi.py is just example form documentation it shows this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWSXb.png). Almost as if the spark was working but the python file is not executed...

I also tried with different python files such as: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfyvr.png) with command: ***C:\Users\User\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7>bin\spark-submit C:\Users\User\Desktop\Big_Data\try.py C:\Users\User\Desktop\Big_Data\pg100.txt***

And results are as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3LO3.png)

No output, errors, nothing, maybe someone has any idea what is wrong???

Clarifying: basically there is no output or execution of python file when calling spark form cmd console

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Spark's Quick Start Guide examples](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications), can you run this command:

```
bin\spark-submit --master local C:\Users\User\Desktop\Big_Data\pi.py
```

More info regarding spark-submit can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit).